# iOS in-app purchase auto-renewable subscriptions free trial option not available?

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, subscription

From apple's documentation it is possible to offer free trials to users, after which they will be auto-billed at the end of the trial

> If you offer a free trial, it will begin when a user subscribes. They
>   will be automatically charged when the free trial is over, unless they
>   have turned off auto-renewal. If you choose to offer a free trial, a
>   drop-down menu will be displayed that will allow you to select the
>   free trial duration.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/13_ManagingIn-AppPurchases_Robert/ManagingIn-AppPurchases.html

Now i don't see this option available when i create a new auto-renewing subscription.

I see a screen like this as shown in docs
[image]

Does someone know where to enable this or is it even possbile?

Or do i have to manually develop the feature by saving the free trial start date?

Comment: I can't answer your question, but there is a some more tantalizing information in Table 12-5 of the URL you cite, where it lists a Free Trial as one of the available options, for regular In-App Purchases.

Answer (score 3):

In iTunes, free trial auto-renewing subscriptions are only available for apps that are managed as newsstand applications.  You can verify this if you create a new app and mark it as newsstand and then created an auto-renewing product.

Cheers!

Joel

Comment: Hey, I think you may be confusing this with a "Free Subscription" which is only available to newstand applications. From apple doc "Free Subscription" is listed under types of in-app purchases: Free Subscription - 
Free subscriptions are a way for developers to put free subscription content in Newsstand. Once a user signs up for a free subscription, it will be available on all devices associated with the user’s Apple ID. Note that free subscriptions do not expire and can only be offered in Newsstand-enabled apps.

Answer (score 0):

For those who have faced with the same issue: Apple has updated their documentation and now it says (please note highlighted paragraph):

"If you offer a free trial, it will begin when a user subscribes. The user will be automatically charged when the free trial is over, unless the user has turned off auto-renewal. If you choose to offer a free trial, a drop-down menu will be displayed that will allow you to select the free trial duration.

**You must have an existing issue to offer a free trial. If you have no issues added in the Manage Newsstand page, you will not see the option to add a free trial.**"

However, in my case it was enough to just enable Newsstand mode in Manage Newsstand section of my application.

Now I can see Free trial option on Duration and Pricing screen of my auto-renewable subscription.

Answer (score -2):

You forgot to make one option as `YES`.  Set `Offer a marketing opt-in incentive?` to `YES` when you are adding `Duration` to your `Auto Renewable Subscription`. You'll have a another `Option box` for how many `days` your `Incentive Duration`.  The duration periods may be

```
 - 7 days
 - 1 Month
 - 2 Months
 - 3 Months
 - 6 Months
 - 1 Year
```

Check out the screenshot 
[image]

Comment: The marketing incentive and duration is distinct from the free trial. Apple certainly hints that it is there, but I can't find it either. Check the help on the marketing opt-in:

"As an incentive, customers will get a free subscription extension when they opt in to receive marketing. This extension is in addition to any free trial that you may choose to offer with the subscription."