# IOS storekit subscription free trial not working

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I've got a subscription product for my IOS app; I want to change it to allow a free trial. I've edited the subscription in Itunes Connect to allow a free trial, however when I try to subscribe to the product, I get the standard message about buying a sub, not the free trial message. Is there any specific thing that I need to do to trigger the free trial, or do I need to create a new subscription product from scratch for it to pick up the free trial, instead of editing?

Comment: There seems to be virtually no information about how subscription products are supposed to work in Apple's documentation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for free trails to work, the app **needs** to be a newsstand app.

Free trails are individually tied to a specific user and any individual user can only get the trial once. After the initial trial, It will ask for money. Try creating a new account and then trying with that account.

Read the Documentation At the following places:

[Apple Developer(Requires Login)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013727-CH1-SW1)

[StoreKit on iOS - autorenewable subscription - How to know whether it is a free trial or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16912969/storekit-on-ios-autorenewable-subscription-how-to-know-wether-it-is-a-free-t/17088975#17088975)

Comment: Do you have a source for your info about the newsstand requirement, or do you just know from personal experience? Thanks very much for the response!

Comment: Both! Here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15388863/ios-in-app-purchase-auto-renewable-subscriptions-free-trial-option-not-available

Comment: Cool, thanks for the help! It seems frustrating to me that you can mark a subscription product as having a free trial in Itunes, but that it won't actually work unless the app is a Newsstand app. I'd love to offer a free trial but I don't want to hide my app away in Newsstand! Still, thanks very much for the help.

Comment: I believe the Newsstand requirement no longer exists. We are adding free trials to our non-Newsstand app and it is working.